# Center RelativeLayout, including ellipsising TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to horizontally-center two textviews, where the left textview has to ellipse if the group exceeds the parent's width. The most obvious solution would be the code below, but unfortunately all views are squashed together in the center. How can I do this?

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/card_title_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/card_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"                
            android:text="shorttideddeddedtle"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/card_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/card_time"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:text="20:00"
            android:textColor="#a0a0a0"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

Should be:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the image of expected and current output?

Comment: I added the images, and simplified the problem code.

Comment: You seem to have confused the two TextView ids (i.e. the time 20:00 is being displayed in the textview named card_title rather than the one named card_time.) If you switch the ids round and change your toLeftOf in the second TextView to be toRightOf I think you will be closer to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an attribute to position the `card_time` view:

Add:

`android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

to your `card_time` view; otherwise, it's defaulting to aligning to the left side of the parent.